# adding a padding to text in compose does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a constraint layout in compose and a Text which has a longer text and the text gets hidden at the end,

I have added padding 16.dp but that does not work. when I add 26.dp the text shifts to next row.

why 16dp does not work here, is there any other way so the text is shifted to next row without adjusting the padding?

[image]

```
fun PCapSection(
    state: ESettingsTileState,
    onPCapSelected: () -> Unit
) {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(
                brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        md_theme_lucent_blue_start,
                        md_theme_lucent_blue_end
                    )
                )
            )
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable {
                onPCapSelected()
            }
    ) {
        val (dollarIcon, pCapTitleText, pCapValueText) = createRefs()
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.p_cap_dollar),
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(26.dp)
                .constrainAs(dollarIcon) {
                    start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = 16.dp)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 20.dp)
                },
            tint = Color.White,
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.home_screen_e_settings_p_cap),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
            color = md_theme_light_onPrimary,
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(pCapTitleText) {
                    start.linkTo(dollarIcon.end, 10.dp)
                    top.linkTo(dollarIcon.top)
                }
        )
        Text(
         
            text = "state of charge 1234567891234567",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall,
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(pCapValueText) {
                    top.linkTo(pCapTitleText.bottom, margin = 12.dp)
                    start.linkTo(pCapTitleText.start)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom, margin = 20.dp)
                }
                .padding(end = 16.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

thanks in advance
R

Comment: you have to link the `end` of the text to `parent.end`

Comment: that will centre the text but I dont want text to be centred

Comment: you have to also set `width = Dimension.fillToConstraints` inside `constrainAs` block then

Comment: that worked thank you so much